# Is this weak singleton implementation in Java thread-safe (and GC-safe)?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, singleton, weak-references

I want to achieve the following results:

- I want to have no more than one instance of the class around. When there are multiple references to the class, I want them all to refer to the same instance.
- I don't want the instance around unless it is needed. Specifically, I want the garbage collector to be able to reclaim the instance when not in use, and recreate it the next time an instance is requested.
- Multiple threads may request an instance, hence the operation must be thread-safe.

This is the code I came up with:

```
public final class MyClass {
    private static WeakReference<MyClass> instance;
    public static synchronized MyClass getInstance() {
        if ((instance == null) || (instance.get() == null)) {
            instance = new WeakReference<MyClass>(new MyClass());
        }
        // TODO what if GC strikes here?
        return instance.get();
    }
}
```

Design choices were:

- Lazy initialization so the instance doesn’t get created unless needed
- The class keeps a WeakReference to the instance so the instance can get garbage-collected when it is no longer used.
- The `getInstance()` method is `synchronized` (to `MyClass`) so that it can only be executed by one thread at a time.

Questions:

- Will this design behave as I expect it to and yield the desired result?
- Do I have to worry about `getInstance()` getting interrupted by the garbage collector where the comment is (meaning the garbage collector would reclaim the instance I was just about to return)? If so, how can I work around it?

Comment: you could have some `MyClass actualInstance` at the start of the method `getInstance()` and instead of passing the new object to the constructor, set `actualInstance = new MyClass()` and pass `actualInstance `to the constructor-call. Look at [Scott Chamberlain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218838/4216641) for a working example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold a local copy of `MyClass` in a variable instead of just giving your only copy of the reference in to the constructor of `WeakRefrence`. This will prevent the GC from collecting `instance` between the `new WeakReference<MyClass>` call and the function returning.

```
public final class MyClass {
    private static WeakReference<MyClass> instance;
    public static synchronized MyClass getInstance() {
        MyClass classInstance = null;
        if (instance != null) {
            classInstance = instance.get();
            if(classInstance != null)
            {
                return classInstance;
            }
        }

        classInstance = new MyClass();
        instance = new WeakReference<MyClass>(classInstance);

        //This is now a strong reference and can't be GC'ed between the previous line and this one.
        return classInstance;
    }
}
```